# Can you crawl between the ground and under the middle of the cable?

Tags: geometry

Two vertical posts are in level ground at 150 feet apart.  A bendable cable,
but one that does not stretch from its original length, is 150 feet and 
1 inch in length.  The cable is fastened in between the two vertical posts at ground level on each side.

The middle point of the cable is lifted up until it is taut, and the 
ground and the middle sections of the cable form an obtuse isosceles 
triangular shape.

Is there room enough for you to crawl through in the space between 
the ground and underneath
the middle of the cable?

***  The length of the cable has been edited.  ***

Comment: Why isn't there spoiler formatting in comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a math problem and is dependent upon the size of the person reading it as to the validity.

Comment: Math puzzles are math problems anyway.  It's a math puzzle.  It's a variation of a math puzzle that I read in a puzzle book.  There is no need to put it on hold or to vote to close this question.  I am an expert on many puzzles, and I am surprised that someone would deem this not a puzzle.

Comment: It doesn't say where along the posts the cable is fastened. If the posts are 20 feet high and the cable is fastened to the top, then the answer is obvious. Source: you can walk under power lines.

Comment: I edited the problem for the cables being attached at ground level.

Comment: @OliveStemforn Personally I love math puzzles, and often I also disagree with certain math puzzles being closed for being off-topic but this isn't a puzzle at all. This is all just basic geometry. It's the same as if you were to post a puzzle that only said "What is 1 + 1?". It's just too basic for it to be considered a puzzle, there is nothing puzzling about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

> Probably? I mean, assuming you can pretty much just lie on the ground and scoot?

because

> The isosceles triangle is also two right triangles with bases of $900$ inches and hypotenuses of $900.25$ inches, making the altitude about $21$ inches (actually $21.214676523$ish)

**WITH NEW CABLE LENGTH**

> still yeah. I mean it's even longer. of course.

Comment: That's a commando crawl, which, I guess, is still technically a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes. Because each side of the cable can be considered an isosceles triangle with a right angle. We know the ground is 75 feet or 900 inches on each side, and the taut cable above it would be 900.25 inches. 
> 900² = 810,000 
> 900.25² = 810,450.0625
>  The positive square root of 450.0625 is about 21.2146765...
>  That should be enough room for most fit people, though it might be tight.